# Extra line break and horizontal space at \begin{document}

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I am trying to insert some text right at the beginning of the document with `\AtBeginDocument` while using `lualatex` and the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{X}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\AtBeginDocument{X}
\begin{document}
X
\end{document}
```

The output is

> X
>
> X_X

where the `_` is really a space. If I remove the `fontspec` package my MWE produces

> XXX

with no spaces. This is what I want, but of course I also want to use `fontspec`. How do I figure out where the line break and space are coming from. Is there a reason that `fontspec` does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fontspec sets up a lot of stuff in the begin document hook, if you modify your example to

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{X}
\show\@begindocumenthook
\usepackage{fontspec}
\show\@begindocumenthook
\AtBeginDocument{X}
\begin{document}
X
\end{document}
```

Then TeX stops with

```
> \@begindocumenthook=macro:
->X.
```

the first time, but then after loading fontspec it shows

```
> \@begindocumenthook=macro:
->\RequirePackage {graphics}X\clist_map_inline:Nn \@filelist {\seq_gput_right:N
o \g__file_record_seq {\tl_to_str:n {##1}}}\cs_if_exist:NTF \__driver_color_ens
ure_current: {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \color_ensure_current: {\__driver_col
or_ensure_current: }}{\cs_if_exist:NT \set@color {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \
color_ensure_current: {\set@color }}}\cs_if_exist:NF \color {\DeclareRobustComm
and \color [2][]{}}\fontspec_patch_verbatim: \fontspec_patch_moreverb: \fontspe
c_patch_fancyvrb: \fontspec_patch_listings: \@TestForInputenc \@cleanupafterinp
utenc \let \textdotacute \tipaDOTacuteaccent \let \textgravedot \tipagraveDOTac
cent \let \textipa \tipacatchonechar \let \rtone \TIPArtonebar \let \stone \TIP
Astonebar \let \tone \TIPAtonebar \@ifpackageloaded {linguex}{\let \implementTI
PAtextx \implementTIPAtextxx }{}\GPT@fix \GPT@PatchTrig \GPT@LoadSuppPdf \ltx@I
fUndefined {define@key}{}{\define@key {Gin}{natwidth}{}\define@key {Gin}{nathei
ght}{}}\@ifpackageloaded {pst-pdf}{}{\@ifpackageloaded {pdftricks}{}{\RequirePa
ckage {pdftexcmds}[2007/11/11]\expandafter \ifx \csname pdf@shellescape\endcsna
me \relax \else \ifnum \pdf@shellescape >0 \RequirePackage {epstopdf-base}[2009
/07/12]\fi \fi }}\DeclareUTFmathsymbols {EU2}\fontspec_maybe_setup_maths: .
l.6 \show\@begindocumenthook
```

and something in that is making a paragraph break.

The easiest thing to do is make sure you load fontspec before or (much better) after adding any text, unless your real use case mean the easy option is not available. Note that the text set before fontspec's code is set before it has set up the fonts, so probably wrong anyway in general.

Comment: That explains the paragraph break (to some extent) between the first and second X, but what about the extra horizontal space between the second and third X? I probably should edit the question to have one of those nifty underscore type spaces.

Comment: well if you start horizontal mode in the hook (which is brave anyway) then a space character in the hook will make a space instead of being ignored If you put a `%` after `\begin{document}` the space will go (note fontspec is doing \RequrirePackage in the hook so you will only get `XXX` if no package file that is loaded has a blank line or a line ending with `}`

Comment: The fontspec package is also patching `\document`, I think in a lazy way, such that `\document` no longer ends with `\ignorespaces`. I can fix the spacing issue now with `\g@addto@macro{\document}{\ignorespaces} after loading the fontspec package.